# Is accessing a integer as a character array differs on different machine and environment

Tags: c, pointers, integer

Here is my code

```
int c = 10;
char *ch = &c;
ch[0] = 'a';
ch[1] = 'b';
ch[2] = 'c';
ch[4] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",ch);
printf("%x\n",c);
printf("%d\n",c);
```

output is `abc` `636261` and `6513249` which in my opinion correct, but is it a standard result or it varies on different machine for example the output of the second `printf` is like`616263`? or in some machines it will be illegal to do so?
Edit : I tried it in Ideone.Com also giving me the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but is it a standard result or it varies on different machine for example the output of the second printf is like616263

The execution character set is not required to be ASCII, for example on a system with EBCDIC you'll get a different result.

> (C99, 5.2.1p1) "The values of the members of the execution character set are implementation-defined."

Moreover the size of an `int` is not required to be 32-bit and for example on a system with 16-bit `int` your program is undefined behavior. And as noted in the comment you will get an different result if your system is big-endian (`616263` instead of `636261` in your little-endian system).

Comment: Good answer (+1). I think the OP may also be referring to whether the byte order at the word level is the same on different platforms.

Comment: It also violates strict aliasing rules. An optimizing compiler is allowed to beat you with a stick for this sort of pointer punning. (it is allowed to assume that a `char*` cannot refer to an `int` for optimisation purposes, so among other things, changes to one may not affect the other even if they would refer to the same thing with strict aliasing rules set aside)

Comment: @Wintermute the program does not violate aliasing rules (but `char *ch = &c;` should be `char *ch = (char *) &c;`). Aliasing rules allows any object to be accessed through a character type.

Comment: Is there any "detailed" documentation about strict aliasing rules?

Comment: There's a [post on the Qt Blog](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/) with further links and examples of things that broke because of this. The code in the examples is technically C++, but it does not depend on C++ features and he reasons from C, so it should work for you.

Comment: @Sab the reference is 6.5p7 in the C11 Standard. Otherwise there are some details in this post for example: http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-kern/2003/08/11/0001.html